# 3 Ubuntu Machines with no networking this morning

Tags: networking, ethernet

Run a variety of Windows, MAC and Ubuntu machines in our office. Everything working fine, well until this morning when 3 of the Ubuntu machines are all showing no network but ethernet cables (and Wifi) settings untouched since Friday.

Bit of messing around with the connections and had no joy this morning. They're all showing `Connection failed Activation of network connection failed`. I could understand one failing over the weekend, but 3 ? And both the Wifi and Ethernet failing.

Grabbed a USB and booted up from a fresh download of 23.04 and got the same issue - this on 2 different machines.

Reformatted one of the machines, installed 23.04 and same issue. Tried a virgin "try Ubuntu" on the other machine and same issue.

Been using Ubuntu for 10 years+ and have never seen anything like this - suggestions? Appreciate it might have been an update that caused the issue, but a fresh copy of 23.04 surely would have resolved that ?

Lastly - it's likely a false positive but noticed over the weekend our Synology box Quarantined a file labeled as `Unix.Malware.Kaiji-10003916-0 - prometheus`

Windows and MAC machines working fine, and 2 Ubuntu machines running 22.04 and 20.04 running fine...

```
ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:23:24:cc:a0:73 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp0s31f6
3: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:ef:18:4f:fc:86 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::5ac8:c13d:d002:cff/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 99
       serial: 84:ef:18:4f:fc:86
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic firmware=29.4063824552.0 7265D-29.ucode latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:125 memory:df000000-df001fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: eno1
       version: 31
       serial: 00:23:24:cc:a0:73
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.19.0-43-generic duplex=full firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:123 memory:df100000-df11ffff


ifconfig -a
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:23:24:cc:a0:73  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 24641  bytes 2100911 (2.1 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 27  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 482  bytes 116491 (116.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xdf100000-df120000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 17096  bytes 3061579 (3.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 17096  bytes 3061579 (3.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::5ac8:c13d:d002:cff  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 84:ef:18:4f:fc:86  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 461  bytes 84832 (84.8 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 774  bytes 181455 (181.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Unattended-upgrades.log
2023-06-09 11:23:23,107 WARNING Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
2023-06-09 11:23:23,107 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2023-06-09 11:23:23,108 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2023-06-09 11:23:23,108 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-06-09 11:23:23,108 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-06-09 11:23:28,194 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
2023-06-12 10:43:15,017 WARNING Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
2023-06-12 10:43:15,017 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2023-06-12 10:43:15,018 INFO Allowed origins are: o=Ubuntu,a=jammy, o=Ubuntu,a=jammy-security, o=UbuntuESMApps,a=jammy-apps-security, o=UbuntuESM,a=jammy-infra-security
2023-06-12 10:43:15,018 INFO Initial blacklist: 
2023-06-12 10:43:15,018 INFO Initial whitelist (not strict): 
2023-06-12 10:43:19,213 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

Comment: On which layer of the OSI model have you identified the problem?

Comment: Check which apps were updated if automatic updates was set up. Look for the ones related to networking. Roll them beck and see if that helps.

Comment: One assumes that you rebooted your router already?

Answer (score 0):

user535733 - I read your comment and then instantly moved on as it couldn't be the router as all the other machines were fine. Had a slightly different problem yesterday, rebooted the router and everything now working fine.
Sigh. So busy on fixing the problem 'cos it must be complicated, you know ? :-)

Thanks everyone who responded...